# why $\frac{a}{b}\pmod p=\frac{a\pmod p}{b\pmod p}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

It is said this following is  theorem？ what's this name? and How to prove it? Thanks

> show that
>   $$\dfrac{a}{b}\pmod p=\dfrac{a\pmod p}{b\pmod p},a,b\in N^{+},(a,p)=1,(b,p)=1$$

Comment: What do you mean by $x \text{ (mod } p)$ where $x\in \mathbb{Q}-\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: $ab\equiv 1\pmod p$, then $\dfrac{1}{a}\equiv b\pmod p$

Comment: $x\equiv(a/b)\pmod p$ means $bx\equiv a\pmod p$. If $x=(a\pmod p)/(b\pmod p)$ means anything, it means $bx\bmod p=a\bmod p$, which is the same as $bx\equiv a\pmod p$, and we're done.